# How to make string, a table name in Lua

Tags: string, lua, lua-table

I have a Lua table like this:

```
table2 = {}
```

and I have a value which is:

```
value = 2
```

and then, I want to declare table name via that value like this:

```
tableName = "table"..value
```

But it returns nil it doesn't declares table name by that.

Can anyone tell me how can I make that? I mean, if I have multiple tables like `table1` `table2` `table3` ... `tableN` ... How can I declare it via this format:

```
tablename = "table"..value
```

Comment: The language must **explicitly not be called "LUA".** All-capps hurts anyway. Its proper name is Lua.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
tableName = "table" .. value
```

`tableName` is a string that has the value `"table2"`, note that it's preferred to use `tostring` like this:

```
tableName = "table" .. tostring(value)
```

Either way, if `table2` is global, you can use `_G[tableName]` to access it.

Comment: might be more efficient to use `_ENV` instead of `_G`.

Comment: Well i tried this:

    tableName = "table" .. tostring(value)

but returned nil. I'll try _G and _ENV, table is global anyways.

Comment: @user3762712 This question has been closed as a duplicate, if my answer and the answers of the duplicate question doesn't solve your problem, Learn [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), and edit your question if you don't think it's a duplicate, or ask a new question otherwise.